# How to get permission level of a folder?

Tags: delphi, permissions, windows-7, administrator

I want to detect a folder, if needs Administrator privilege level (using `Delphi`). Is it possible?

I wrote this Code. This is what exactly I want. But I want to do this using Windows standard functions.

```
// Check if You need Administrator-level access to create a folder
try
  mkdir(SDirectory + '\~TEST');
except
  on E: exception do
  begin
    if E.message = 'File access denied' then
    begin
      MessageBox(self.Handle,
        'You need Administrator-level access to create this folder', '', MB_ICONERROR);
      exit;
    end;
  end;
end;
RmDir(SDirectory + '\~TEST');
```

Comment: Why down-voted? is there any problem in my question? please help me to fix it :)

Comment: This question is not answerable. It is too imprecise. "needs Administrator privilege level" to do what? To read? To write? To delete? And so on. Could you also explain why you need to detect this, since there may be a better solution.

Comment: This will fail on non-English OS I guess. Better to test for `GetLastError=ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`.

Comment: How do you read the conclusion that admin rights are needed? There could be other reasons for the failure.

Comment: Yes, I know but as i said I'm looking for a better way. (a standard way)

Comment: you must use the `GetFileSecurity` function to retrieve the information about the security of a directory  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446639%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: @Kermia Once you've read all about Windows security, access control lists and so on, you'll realise that you are entering a hornet's nest. Do you really want to go this way, or is there some easier route?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following example is translated from [this article](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=4318). It can be used for determination if the file or directory has the access rights noticed in [that article](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=4318) for every user, so if I ask for FILE_ALL_ACCESS then it means that everyone has the full access to the desired file or directory. Note that in the following code there's no exception handling and that I can't even remember when I've used VB last time so it might be wrong so take this as an inspiration and feel free to modify this post.

```
const
  FILE_READ_DATA = $0001;
  FILE_WRITE_DATA = $0002;
  FILE_APPEND_DATA = $0004;
  FILE_READ_EA = $0008;
  FILE_WRITE_EA = $0010;
  FILE_EXECUTE = $0020;
  FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES = $0080;
  FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES = $0100;
  FILE_GENERIC_READ = (STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ or FILE_READ_DATA or
    FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES or FILE_READ_EA or SYNCHRONIZE);
  FILE_GENERIC_WRITE = (STANDARD_RIGHTS_WRITE or FILE_WRITE_DATA or
    FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES or FILE_WRITE_EA or FILE_APPEND_DATA or SYNCHRONIZE);
  FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE = (STANDARD_RIGHTS_EXECUTE or FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES or
    FILE_EXECUTE or SYNCHRONIZE);
  FILE_ALL_ACCESS = STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED or SYNCHRONIZE or $1FF;

function CheckFileAccess(const FileName: string; const CheckedAccess: Cardinal): Cardinal;
var Token: Cardinal;
    Status: LongBool;
    Access: Cardinal;
    SecDescSize: Cardinal;
    PrivSetSize: Cardinal;
    PrivSet: PRIVILEGE_SET;
    Mapping: GENERIC_MAPPING;
    SecDesc: PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR;
begin
  Result := 0;
  GetFileSecurity(PChar(Filename), OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION or GROUP_SECURITY_INFORMATION or DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, nil, 0, SecDescSize);
  SecDesc := GetMemory(SecDescSize);

  if GetFileSecurity(PChar(Filename), OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION or GROUP_SECURITY_INFORMATION or DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, SecDesc, SecDescSize, SecDescSize) then
  begin
    ImpersonateSelf(SecurityImpersonation);
    OpenThreadToken(GetCurrentThread, TOKEN_QUERY, False, Token);
    if Token <> 0 then
    begin
      Mapping.GenericRead := FILE_GENERIC_READ;
      Mapping.GenericWrite := FILE_GENERIC_WRITE;
      Mapping.GenericExecute := FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE;
      Mapping.GenericAll := FILE_ALL_ACCESS;

      MapGenericMask(Access, Mapping);
      PrivSetSize := SizeOf(PrivSet);
      AccessCheck(SecDesc, Token, CheckedAccess, Mapping, PrivSet, PrivSetSize, Access, Status);
      CloseHandle(Token);
      if Status then
        Result := Access;
    end;
  end;

  FreeMem(SecDesc, SecDescSize);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if CheckFileAccess('C:\Windows', FILE_ALL_ACCESS) = FILE_ALL_ACCESS then
    ShowMessage('C:\Windows has full access for everyone')
  else
    ShowMessage('Someone has no full access to C:\Windows');
end;
```

[image]
with Delphi 2007 on 64-bit Windows 7 Enterprise SP 1

---

Anyway much more easier would be to download [JEDI Windows Security Code Library](http://blog.delphi-jedi.net/security-library/) and follow the example like [this one](http://jedi-apilib.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/jedi-apilib/jwscl/branches/0.9.1/examples/FileSecurity/Get/ReadFileSecurity.dpr) (I hope it works also for directories but I'm pretty sure it will).

Answer (score 3):

Small change on the example above, for those who have moved to Delphi XE2 and up (Token no longer works with Cardinal, has to be THandle).

```
function getFileAccess(...):Cardinal;
var
    Token: THandle;//No longer Cardinal
begin
    { ... code ...}
    if GetFileSecurity({...params...}) then
    begin
        //... more stuff
        OpenThreadToken(GetCurrentThread,TOKEN_QUERY,false,Token);
        if Token<>0 then
        begin
            //... more stuff
            AccessCheck(SecDesc,Token,CheckedAccess,Mapping,PrivSet,PrivSetSize,Access,Status);
            CloseHandle(Token);
            //... more stuff
        end;
    end;
    //....more stuff
end;
```