# Best way to check for write permissions on a binary file with Delphi

Tags: file, delphi, permissions

I need a way to find if a user can to *write to a binary file*.

Users *might not* have write permission for a directory and its contents. They can, however, create new files and modify them - so testing this by creating a new file in the directory is not accurate.

The following appears to do the trick, is it the best way to do it, and is it safe?

```
function IsExistingBinaryFileWriteable(const aName : String): Boolean;
var
  testFile: File;
begin
  Result := False;
  if not FileExists(aName) then Exit;
  try
    AssignFile(testFile, aName);
    FileMode := fmOpenWrite;
    Reset(testFile); // open
    Result := True;
  finally
    CloseFile(testFile);
  end;
end;
```

If Reset(testFile) fails, result will not be set to True.
It seems to test ok for me, I'm just concerned about the safety of using Reset() like this, and if it modifies the file in any way?

Comment: Your function might raise an exception in addition to returning `True` or `False`; that's not good. I think you mustn't call `CloseFile` if `AssignFile` or `Reset` fails. But `Reset` should not alter the file. In any case, feel free to stop using legacy Pascal I/O.

Comment: "If Reset(testFile) fails, result will not be set to True." If `Reset` raises, it is true that the function won't return `True`. **But it will not return `False` either, because it will not return at all.** The user of your fcn needs to handle all three cases: ret `True`, ret `False`, and exception. That's bad.

Comment: Thanks @AndreasRejbrand! You're right I should handle the exception properly. Do you have suggestions for alternatives re "stop using legacy Pascal I/O"?

Comment: `TFileStream`, perhaps?

Comment: This code can do one of three things. 1. Return `False` if the file does not exist. 2. Raise an exception if IO error checking is enabled. 3. Return `True`. It doesn't match the behaviour implied by the name `IsExistingBinaryFileWriteable`.

Comment: Generally a function like `IsExistingBinaryFileWriteable` shouldn't even be written. If you need to write to the file, try to write to it. If you can't write to it, deal with that when it happens. After all, you need to deal with that scenario no matter what. You shouldn't try to pre-empt that failure mode.

Comment: Thanks @DavidHeffernan, yeah I've tidied up the exception handling. The full scenario isn't as straight-forward as the given scenario; too much to get into here, but it is more about determining the reason something else (not in our control, and pretty-much irreplaceable right now) has failed against a few reasons we know it could have been.

Comment: sorry, [return] submits (noob); so yes, it is the opposite of preempting, and we don't have anything to write yet. Thanks again!

Comment: That makes no real sense to me. Invariably when people think they want to do this, the better way is EAFP (it's easier to ask for forgiveness than permission)

Comment: I appreciate that and your time helping me here thanks so much. This is one of those cases where there's too much context to explain. So the question itself remains: Assuming we do need to - what is the best way to *check* that a user can write to a binary file?
(EAFP implies attempting to write to the file, which the example does.. so is there a better way to do the same?) edit: well the example *begins* to, at least :)

Comment: Maybe it will help to consider if from a reporting perspective? We're not trying to write anything to a file right now.. we just want to inform the user if they could do it.

Comment: If you are interested only in reporting the user whether it can modify certain file or not then I guess the best way would be to read [File Security and Access Rights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-security-and-access-rights) information for that specific file. As far as I know Delphi does not contain required Libraries to do this so you will either have call needed WIN API calls manually or look for an existing third part library.

Answer (score 0):

You must change your function because it can't catch IO error

```
function IsExistingBinaryFileWriteable(const aName : String): Boolean;
var
  testFile: File;
begin
  Result := False;
  if not FileExists(aName) then Exit;
  AssignFile(testFile, aName);
  FileMode := fmOpenWrite;
  try
    Reset(testFile); // open
  except
    Exit(False);
  end;
  Result := True;
  CloseFile(testFile);
end;
```

But, this function don't check the permission, this is only check you can write on file or not. What is difference, Think you have a file that you have permission to change it but with readonly properties. this function return False instead of True.

I prefer to use this [CheckFileAccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908152/how-to-get-permission-level-of-a-folder) function instead.

And for checking write access you can use this condition

```
CheckFileAccess(yourFileName, FILE_GENERIC_WRITE) = FILE_GENERIC_WRITE
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the exception handling, had changed from previous comments but not updated. The link to CheckFileAccess doesn't appear to contain a complete example, but I get the idea.